# Calculating voltage in piezoelectric material

Tags: electric-fields, piezoelectric

The piezoelectric constitutive law is defined by the two equations:

$$S=s T+dE\\
D=d T+\epsilon E$$

$S$: Strain. $T$: Stress. $E$: Electric field. $D$: electric charge-density displacement. $\epsilon$: Permittivity (evaluated at constant stress). $d$: piezoelectric strain constant. $s$: Elastic compliance (evaluated at constant electric field).

Apart from that we have the expression:

$$g=\frac{d}{\epsilon}$$

$g$ is piezoelectric voltage constant (or open-circuit constant).

For a piezoelectric material we can look up $g$, $d$, $\epsilon$ and $s$ in data tables, and let's assume that all other material data can be found likewise if needed. I also know the physical lenght/height $L$ of my material bulk. If I calculate the electric field generated at a certain applied stress $T$, then I can use that $E$ to find the voltage over the material piece:

$$V=EL$$

BUT I am stuck trying to calculate the $E$. I feel that I do not know $D$ and $S$ in the above equations. I am even unsure of exactly what the $E$ in those equations is - isn't it the generated electric field?

Thank you in advance and good day.

Comment: I assume you have looked [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity)?

Comment: @honeste_vivere Sure. It doesn't explain or give an example of an actual calculation. For example a quote from the wikipedia page: `a 1 cm3 cube of quartz with 2 kN (500 lbf) of correctly applied force can produce a voltage of 12500 V` - how is this calculation performed? How is electric field found to calculate the voltage?

Comment: I just sent the link because it defined the variables in the equations you showed and you asked for the definition of E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the material is not connected to a circuit and doesn't have any external charges added then $D =0$ so you can use
$$
D= dT + \epsilon E = 0
$$
along with the known stress $T$ to obtain $E$. Then use $V=EL$ to obtain the voltage $V$.

Here's a screenshot from [Learnpiezo.org video series Lecture 3 Part F](http://www.learnpiezo.org/lecture-3-piezoelectric-material-properties) which covers the situation you described.

[image]